Can anyone tell me why this program shows a runtime error?
There are no errors in the compiler. So, I submitted it to the online judge. I get correct answers when there is no runtime error. And all the samples are also showing correct answer. I also tried putting it into valgrind, but it also returns 0 errors from 0 contexts.
The problem is this: https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc142/tasks/abc142_d
The judgement was this: https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc142/submissions/56105082
My program is this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    long long a,b,l,k=0,t,cd=0;
    scanf("%lld %lld",&a,&b);
    if(a>=b){
        l=a;
    } else{
        l=b;
    }

    long long comdiv[l];
    
    for(long long i=1;i<l+1;i++){//common divisor
        if(a%i==0 && b%i==0){
            comdiv[k]=i;
            k++;
        }
    }
    cd=k;
    k=k-1;
    t=comdiv[k];
    
    for(long long i=1;i<t+1;i++){
        long long co=0;
        for(long long in=0;in<=k;in++){
            if(comdiv[in]==i){
                continue;
            }
            else if(comdiv[in]%i==0 && co<=2){
                co++;
                if(co==2){cd--;}
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("%lld",cd);
}


Consider how much memory you are using when A and B are close to the maximum values of 10^12.

You can factor a number < 10^12 with a table of primes < 10^6.

Variable-length arrays such as your comdiv are a trap for inexperienced C programmers.  Avoid them until you understand well how to use them safely, and maybe even then.  If you don't know until runtime how large an array you need, then use dynamic allocation.

Thank you, sirs. I learned how to use dynamic memory allocation and that fixed the runtime error.
